# firefoxでvideoタグを使用した動画再生の際に発生するrangeエラーについて

Tags: cakephp, apache, firefox, 動画, streaming

**firefox**で動画を再生しているとき、ロードされていない部分（バッファリングされていない部分？）に差し掛かると「ネットワークエラーが発生しましたため動画の再生を中止しました。」
と表示され、動画の再生ができなくなります。
**videoタグ**を用いて実装しており、動画ファイルのサイズはおよそ500MBです。
HTTPの通信内容を確認すると、ちょうどロードされていない部分に差し掛かると、416 Requested range not satisfiable が発生していました。（添付ファイル参照）
これは、**Range** の値がContentsの最大の長さと一致しているのが原因だと思われます。
また、他のブラウザでは再現せず、上記のエラーも発生しません。
rangeリクエストにおけるfirefoxのバグではないかと思い、調べましたが
そのような報告は見つかりませんでした。
なぜfirefoxだけでこのようなエラーが発生するのか、ご存知の方がいれば教えて
頂きたいです。。。
言語は**php(cakephp)**
WEBサーバは**apache** です。ル